# Laravel intelligent array matches

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, relationship

I have a lot of relation in my laravel project.
I started to make a search. Now I have more multidimensional arrays, what I need to check in all array which value is available?!
So my arrays:

```
array:4 [▼
  "bytype" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "price" => 500
      "discount_price" => null
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "price" => 1400
      "discount_price" => null
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
  ]
  "bymake" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "price" => 500
      "discount_price" => null
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "price" => 1400
      "discount_price" => null
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
  ]
  "bymodel" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "price" => 1500
      "discount_price" => null
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
  ]
  "byattribute" => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "price" => 500
      "discount_price" => null
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "price" => 1500
      "discount_price" => null
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    2 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "price" => 1400
      "discount_price" => null
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
  ]
]
```

So how can I do this to get that value(its means that array) which one is available in all of that 4 main array?

to be like that:

```
  "listable" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "price" => 500
      "discount_price" => null
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:6 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "price" => 1400
      "discount_price" => null
      "created_at" => null
      "updated_at" => null
      "pivot" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
  ]
```

--EDIT--
My search controller:

```
$original=$resquest->all();
        $searchableAttributes=$resquest->all();
        if(isset($resquest->type)){
            $type=VehicleType::find($resquest->type);
            $vehicles['bytype']=$type->vehicle()->toArray();
            unset($searchableAttributes['type']);
        }
        if(isset($resquest->make)){
            $make=VehicleMake::find($resquest->make);
            $vehicles['bymake']=$make->vehicle->toArray();
            unset($searchableAttributes['make']);
        }
        if(isset($resquest->model)){
            $model=VehicleModel::find($resquest->model);
            $vehicles['bymodel']=$model->vehicle->toArray();
            unset($searchableAttributes['model']);
        }
        if(!empty($searchableAttributes)){
            foreach ($searchableAttributes as $key => $value) {
                $attribute=VehicleAttributeValue::find($value);
                $vehicles['byattribute']=$attribute->vehicle->toArray();
                
            }
        }
```

Vehicle type model:

```
public function vehicle(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Vehicle','vehicles_types_vehicles','vehicle_type_id','vehicle_id');
    }
```

and all 3 model like this, with different keys, and table

Comment: you better show us ur model and controller.

Comment: What you have done for this till now ?

Comment: If that data is coming from the database you should refine your query to get what you need to begin with, getting more and then reducing it is just inefficient on two ends.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys,code is added,check.

Comment: Can you post an expected output? I cannot understand what you want actually

Comment: I want to check bettween the arrays wich value exisit in all.